# multiple models in one index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing

Is there any way we can list multiple models in one index page?

Like I have 4 models:users, agencies, authorizedpersons and mentors that I would want to list them in one index page.

Is there a specific process that I could follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just to query for all of these in that controller's index action:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @agencies = Agency.all
    @authorized_people = AuthorizedPerson.all
    @mentors = Mentor.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

And reference them in your views as normal:

```
<% @agencies.each do |agency| %>
  <!-- do stuff -->
<% end %>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <!-- do more stuff -->
<% end %>

<!-- etc. -->
```

Comment: I tried your steps but its giving me an error and I can't see the fields while running the application. I did a scaffolding to create model/view/controller files. Now, is it a good way to start off if I want to have multiple models in one view? Do I have to add something to the model file and the db migration files too? guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Rubyuser,

Yes, this is totally normal behavior. In your controller whenever you specify a variable using @myvariable, it is an instance variable available in the scope of the controller and view. A variable without the @ is a local variable only available within that method.

So in your controller when you do:

```
class Foos < ApplicationController
    def index
        @foos = Foo.all
        @bars = Bar.all
    end  
 end
```

You can then reference @foos and @bars from within your view.

```
<h1>My foos and bars</h1>
<table>
 <thead>
   <th>foo</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <% @foos.each do |f| %>
   <tr>
    <td>f.name</td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>

<table>
 <thead>
   <th>bar</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <% @bars.each do |b| %>
   <tr>
    <td>b.name</td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, to keep things more clean, you may want to consider using a partial. Create a file called **_bars_index.html.erb** and copy the table with the bars code in it.

replace it with

```
<%= render "bars_index" %>
```

and now your code is nice and tidy and easy to follow.